# Multi-Class or Multi-Label Classification with LightGBM

Tags: multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification, lightgbm

I am working on a classification project that an outcome may belong to multiple classes. For example, the outcomes may belong to Class A, B, and/or C; e.g., A, B, A&B, A&C, B&C, etc. However, I want to predict the probability of a class. For example, P(A)=Prob of outcome contains Class A; e.g., Pr(A)+Pr(A&B)+Pr(A&C)+Pr(A&B&C).

I prefer using LightGBM for it. My questions are:

1. For LightGBM, do outcome classes have to be mutually exclusive?
2. For LightGBM, what is the difference between multiclass vs multiclassova?
3. If I model it as a multi-label classification (e.g., N-class) problem, is it equivalent to 2^N multi-class classification and each class is one-hot encoded of N classes?

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on how you deal with the probabilities of a given multiclass classification.

For example, LGBM's `.predict()` method returns what class is likely to be occurring in the given observation (highest probability), but if you call `.predict_proba()` it will return N values (N being the number of classes)

So if you're trying to achieve not mutually exclusive predictions, I'd suggest comparing each of these predictions to a certain value, let's say `0.33`, and if the prediction is greater or equal to that value, assign a respective class.